# iPhone - resizing image and two labels to fit the screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm new to iPhone developing. I have a screen with image, title and content:
[image: Screen template]

Image has dynamic size and also all text can have any length. What I want to achievie is to fit the image exactly in screen and make all labels to be only as long as they should be.

Afterk about 5 hours of work I have:

- Working labels length, achieved by setting `Lines=0` and `Preferred Width=content width`
- Not working image, which lefts blank spaces

I have read a lot, I understand `Content Hugging Priority` and `Content Compression Resistance Priority`. I know differences in `UIViewContentMode`. I know that I can manually set `UIImage.frame=CGRectMake(...)`. Nothing works. My image is more wider than higher (lets assume that width/height = 3). If I have `UIViewContentMode=Aspect Fit` then I will have blank space above and below the image. If set to `Aspect fill` then image is too high and also cropped. Changing frame in code doesn't change anything in view. What I want is to have image with size that was made using `Aspect fit`, but without blank space.

Comment: Aspect fit, by definition, will keep the aspect ratio of the image and fit the entire image inside the image view. However, since your image is super wide, there's no way to resize it vertically like you want and still keep the aspect ratio. I don't think what you want to do is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I dit it. First of all, everyone writes that `UIImageView.Frame` should be modified to shrink the image, but be aware, that if your view is `UITableViewCell` then you should do that in `layoutSubviews` method (remember to invoke `super.layoutSubviews()` at the begging).

Secondly, make in IB a height constraint for your `UIImageView` for temporary value (for example 100). You will change that constraint in `layoutSubviews` method.

And finally: fitting image is NOT about its ratio. Set `UIViewContentMode=Aspect Fit`. Then the case with blank top and bottom areas occurs only when the initial image is wider than screen. Calculating the proper height should also take place in `layoutSubviews`.

Example implementation:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    var imageWidth = (imageViewObject.image?.size.width)!
    var imageHeight = (imageViewObject.image?.size.height)!
    var frameWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    var properHeight: CGFloat

    if imageWidth > frameWidth {
        var ratio = frameWidth / imageWidth
        properHeight = imageHeight * ratio
    }
    else {
        properHeight = imageHeight
    }

    imageHeightConstraint.constant = properHeight
    imageViewObject.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frameWidth, properHeight)
}
```